# Remove certain character from column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table that has multiple columns and all the string in that column starts and ends with a semicolon.

following is the table

```
ID             Name
"sdadsa"       "Something" 
"sdadsa"       "Something2" 
"sdadsa"       "Something"
```

I want a SQL query that can remove all these double quotes from the SQL table and should look like.

```
ID             Name
sdadsa       Something 
sdadsa       Something2 
sdadsa       Something
```

Comment: Why not fix the ETL process? I would *guess* that you are importing a CSV file that has quote identified values, and you aren't letting your ETL process known that they are quote identified. Though the answer is simple: use `REPLACE`.

Comment: Is it a semi-colon or a double quote? Can the value ever _also_ be _inside_ the string, too? What is the length of the longest possible string? `PARSENAME()` [is possible](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac3e0d8244b3d43f6d4cd098139f0c94), but it has limitations.

Comment: How was this data imported? This is almost certainly a bug in the import code. You should fix that import code, not try to cover up the bug afterwards. All CSV import libraries can handle quoted fields. All you need to get rid of double quotes is to set the correct parameter. In `BULK INSERT` you need to use the `FIELDQUOTE` parameter, or set `FORMAT='CSV'`

Answer (score 0):

There's is built-in functions you can use to achieve it

```
update table set Name = right(left(Name,LEN(Name)-1),len(Name)-2) where Name like '"%"'
```

same for Id

```
update table set Id = right(left(Id,LEN(Id)-1),len(Id)-2) where Id like '"%"'
```